# How to find common elements on two different length vectors in R?

Tags: r, vector

I need to find common elements in 2 different length vectors.

For example, I have a vector A with 10 elements, and a vector B with 3 elements.

I need get the position of which elements in A is equal to B.

```
A=c(1,2,45,3,10,5,11,13,6,7)

B=c(45,3,10)
```

C would be `[3,4,5]`

I have already tried "match" and "intercept" functions, but no success :(

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Use `match(B,A)`. The order is important (`match(B,A)` is different from `match(A,B)`)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `which` function.

```
> which(A %in% B)
[1] 3 4 5
```